# Finding area between a curve and a line using double integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, graphing-functions, area, volume

We are asked to find the area between the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and the line $x + y = 2$ lying in the first quadrant.

One method is to find the area by integrating $2-x$ from $0$ to $2$ and subtracting that from $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ from $0$ to $2$ 
which gives the answer $\pi - 2$.

If I had to solve this same equation using double integrals, can someone explain the logic behind taking $1$ as the function which is integrating over $y = 2-x$ to $y= \sqrt{4-x^2}$ and $x = 0$ to $x = 2$

I'm aware this is a very basic question but I haven't understood it, sorry.

[image]

Comment: Very similar to what you have written: $\int_0^2 \int_{2-x}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} ~ dy ~ dx$ or $\int_0^2 (\sqrt{4-x^2} - (2-x)) ~ dx$

Comment: Similarly, you can go in the order $dx ~ dy$

Comment: Even if you prefer using double-integrals, a more optimum and easier way to calculate the area of the shaded region in the specified question would be: Area of quadrant - area of triangle $= \frac{\pi \times (2)^2}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \times 2 \times 2$

Comment: @UnexpectedConfusion yess i was just trying to see how many different methods can be used and how they're related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from $dA=dxdy$. To compute the area, you need to find
$$A=\int_Ddx\,dy,$$
where $D$ is the region you are interested in. Now let's try to describe this region $D$. You can cut this region into vertical slices. When $x$ is fixed, $y$ will grow from $2-x$ to $\sqrt{4-x^2}$. So the "height" of the region at this point $x$ is $\int_{2-x}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\,dx$. Then you can integrate over $x$. So you will have
\begin{align*}
A&=\int_D\,dx\,dy\\
&=\int_0^2\left(\int_{2-x}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\,dy\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^2\left[\sqrt{4-x^2}-(2-x)\right]\,dx.
\end{align*}
This can be solved by 1d-calculus.